Can I calculate differential settlement of sand using its compression index?
This is for an undergraduate lab report. I have been asked to calculate differential settlement of a sand layer based on the results of oedometer tests, but I’m not sure how to get there from the quantities we determined in lab.
A fictional cover letter describes the assignment:
“The soil profile below a major portion of the dam consists of poorly graded, medium loose sand (γʹ = 10.5kN/m3) underlain by silty clay; a dense sand is below the clay. The medium sand varies in thickness from 0.5m to 1.5m. A concern in the design of the dam is the differential settlement that may be caused by the variation in thickness. The clay is a uniform deposit 5m thick and provisions can be made for its consolidation, although the rate of settlement is a concern.
“Perform a one-dimensional compression test on the sand and report the stress-strain behavior including the unload-reload response. Transform this data into void ratio (e) and effective stress (σ z ʹ ), and generate the e − log σ zʹ plot. From the diagram, determine the compression index Cc.
“In addition, perform a consolidation test on the silty clay for one load increment, and present deformation versus square-root time. Compute the coefficient of consolidation Cv using the square-root-of-time method.
“Assuming that one-dimensional compression is a valid model for the field behavior, estimate the maximum differential settlement of the sand due a uniform surcharge load of 70kPa and estimate the time required to reach 50% consolidation in the clay. Comment on the deformation characteristics of the two soils with regard to (i) the amount of differential settlement of the sand (≤ 10mm is tolerable) and (ii) the rate of settlement of the clay (the life of the dam, as dictated by the mine, is 5 years).”
In lab, we recorded stress and compression data for dry sand and converted the compression data into void ratios. I’ve attached my e − log σ zʹ plot, which I used to calculate a compression index of 0.0608.

I’m confused as to how I’m meant to apply this data to estimate differential settlement. I think I know how to calculate differential settlement of the clay layer by factoring in how the thicker areas of sand result in a greater load. However, it seems like I’m also meant to consider variations in the immediate settlement of the sand layer, which I don’t know how to do. All of the settlement equations we’ve learned have been specific to saturated clays.
My online research suggests that empirical methods are best for estimating immediate settlement of granular soils. I haven’t seen anything that uses Cc for that purpose.
There’s also a formula for immediate settlement (described here: https://www.slideshare.net/SuezHalder/determination-of-immediate-settlement#2) that shows up later in our textbook. But that formula uses quantities that we weren’t given, and I don’t know if it would be considered one-dimensional compression.
The professor and TA are no longer available for questions, unfortunately. (I got an extension on the lab due to a medical issue.) Any insight would be appreciated!
